# CS50 Recover (Pset4)- Images not Recovered

Tags: c, cs50, recover

So I'm trying CS50 Recover exercise (where you need to search for jpg files in a memory card and whenever you find one- you open a new file and write the jpg found to the new file).
My code compiles but when I'm running the check50 command I'm receiving the following errors:

```
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    recovered image does not match
:( recovers middle images correctly
    recovered image does not match
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    recovered image does not match
```

Can somebody help me figure out what am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Checking if the user entered a correct input:
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("You're not using it correctly!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
// Opening the file in argv[1]
    FILE *f=fopen(argv[1], "r");

// Validating that there's a file in argv[1]
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("File hasn't found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    unsigned char bytes[512];
    int counter=0;
    FILE *img= NULL;
    
    while (fread(bytes, 512, 1, f)==1)
    {   
        if (bytes[0]==0xff && bytes[1]==0xd8 && bytes[2]==0xff && (bytes[3]&0xf0)==0xe0)
        {
            // If it's the first jpg found:
            if (counter==0)
            {
                img=fopen("000.jpg", "w");
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                char filename[8];
                sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg", counter);
                img= fopen(filename, "w");
                if (img==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Couldn't open file\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            counter++;
            fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
        }   
    }
    fclose(img);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, try opening files (both for reading and writing) in bynary mode: add `b` to the mode strings for `fopen()` like `rb` and `wb`.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that you are not handling multiblock files correctly.

You only do the `fwrite` *if* the current block has the header. Otherwise, you are throwing away the data.

That's because the `fwrite` is inside the `if` block that detects the header.

*If* you have encountered the first (i.e. any) header, you will have an open output stream. Therefore, after that, you have to do the `fwrite` on *each* loop iteration.

---

Since you set `img` to `NULL` before entering the outer loop, there is no need to special case the `000.jpg`

And, if the input file did *not* have a header [ever], the final `fclose` would segfault because the `img` pointer would be `NULL`.

---

I've annotated the bugs [with fixes]. I've wrapped the old/new code if `#if 0` blocks:

```
#if 0
// old/original code
#else
// new/refactored code
#endif
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Checking if the user entered a correct input:
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("You're not using it correctly!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Opening the file in argv[1]
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // Validating that there's a file in argv[1]
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("File hasn't found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char bytes[512];
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *img = NULL;

    while (fread(bytes, 512, 1, f) == 1) {
        if (bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xd8 && bytes[2] == 0xff &&
            (bytes[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
// NOTE/BUG: no need to special case the first file
#if 0
            // If it's the first jpg found:
            if (counter == 0) {
                img = fopen("000.jpg", "w");
            }
            else {
                fclose(img);
#else
            if (img != NULL)
                fclose(img);
#endif
                char filename[8];

                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                if (img == NULL) {
                    printf("Couldn't open file\n");
                    return 1;
                }
#if 0
            }
#endif
            counter++;

// NOTE/BUG: this is only executed if the current block has a header string
#if 0
            fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
#endif
        }

// NOTE/FIX: this is the correct placement for the write
#if 1
        if (img != NULL)
            fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
#endif
    }

// NOTE/BUG: if the input file had _no_ header, img will be NULL
#if 0
    fclose(img);
#else
    if (img != NULL)
        fclose(img);
#endif
    fclose(f);
}
```

---

Here's the fully cleaned up and refactored code [*without* the `#if 0`]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Checking if the user entered a correct input:
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("You're not using it correctly!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Opening the file in argv[1]
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // Validating that there's a file in argv[1]
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("File hasn't found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char bytes[512];
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *img = NULL;

    while (fread(bytes, 512, 1, f) == 1) {
        if (bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xd8 && bytes[2] == 0xff &&
            (bytes[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
            if (img != NULL)
                fclose(img);
            char filename[8];

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            if (img == NULL) {
                printf("Couldn't open file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            counter++;
        }

        if (img != NULL)
            fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
    }

    if (img != NULL)
        fclose(img);
    fclose(f);
}
```