# Why does Valgrind give me so many errors?

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind, fwrite, fread

I'm kind of new to programming and I was writing a program to recover JPEG files present in "card.raw" by comparing the 4 continuous bytes. If they demarcated a JPEG the program had to copy a block of 512 bytes into a new file saved a xxx.jpg (000.jpg, 001.jpg, etc). If after the block had been copied, the start of a new JPEG was found, the current file would be closed and the next file would be opened to copy the next JPG. Else the next block would be copied in the same file.

`CODE:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    FILE *recover = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(recover == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERRNO 1 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fseek(recover, 0L, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long size = ftell(recover);
    fseek(recover, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    BYTE *CHUNK = (BYTE*)malloc(size * sizeof(BYTE));
    fread(CHUNK, sizeof(BYTE), size, recover);      //Break recover into bytes
    int j = 0;
    char file[8] = "xxx.jpg";
    FILE *f = NULL;
    int s = 0;
    write1:
    while(j + 3 < size)
    {
        if(CHUNK[j] == 0xff && CHUNK[j + 1] == 0xd8 && CHUNK[j + 2] == 0xff && j + 512 < size)                           //Check if byte is JPEG format 1st byte
        {
                            if(s == 0)
                            {
                                if(f != NULL)
                                {
                                    f = NULL;
                                }
                                sprintf(file ,"%03d.jpg",counter);  //Create custom file of format xxx.jpg
                                printf("SUCCESS\n");
                                f = fopen(file,"w");
                                printf("ERRNO 2 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                if(f == NULL)
                                {
                                    printf("ERRNO 2 is %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                }
                                //printf("ERRNO 2 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                for(int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
                                {
                                    fwrite(&CHUNK[j + k], 512, sizeof(BYTE), f);  //Copy 512 bytes from start of JPEG file as 512 bytes form one 'block'
                                }
                                j += 512; //Increment to check initial bytes of next 'block'
                                s++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fclose(f);
                                counter++;
                                goto write1;
                            }
        }
        else if(s > 0)   //Else continue searching
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
            {
                fwrite(&CHUNK[j + k], 512, sizeof(BYTE), f);  //Copy 512 bytes from start of JPEG file as 512 bytes form one 'block'
            }
            j += 512;
        }
        else j++;
    }
    fclose(recover);
}
```

Running the program gave me this error:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted
```

So, I tried using Valgrind to debug this. However Valgrind gave me this:

```
==4228== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4228== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4228== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4228== Command: ./n card.raw
==4228== 
SUCCESS
ERRNO 2 IS Success
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x5696334: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:48)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 1
==4228==    at 0x56A56A6: _IO_un_link (genops.c:54)
==4228==    by 0x56963EC: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:49)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x56963ED: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x56963F4: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c7b8 is 136 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x5696404: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c818 is 232 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x5696422: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c810 is 224 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x569643D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c7b8 is 136 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x5696444: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid write of size 8
==4228==    at 0x5696446: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c818 is 232 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x569644A: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c814 is 228 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x56A4264: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:131)
==4228==    by 0x5696466: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:53)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c7a0 is 112 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x5696467: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:53)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x569635C: _IO_acquire_lock_fct (libioP.h:797)
==4228==    by 0x569635C: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c7b8 is 136 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x5696363: _IO_acquire_lock_fct (libioP.h:797)
==4228==    by 0x5696363: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c814 is 228 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid write of size 8
==4228==    at 0x5696480: _IO_acquire_lock_fct (libioP.h:797)
==4228==    by 0x5696480: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c818 is 232 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x5696498: _IO_acquire_lock_fct (libioP.h:797)
==4228==    by 0x5696498: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c810 is 224 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x569636D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c808 is 216 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x56A4409: _IO_file_finish@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:170)
==4228==    by 0x569639D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c7a0 is 112 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x56A6D39: _IO_default_finish (genops.c:630)
==4228==    by 0x569639D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c768 is 56 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x56A6D57: _IO_default_finish (genops.c:636)
==4228==    by 0x569639D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c790 is 96 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x56A6D70: _IO_default_finish (genops.c:639)
==4228==    by 0x569639D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c778 is 72 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 1
==4228==    at 0x56A6D86: _IO_un_link (genops.c:54)
==4228==    by 0x56A6D86: _IO_default_finish (genops.c:645)
==4228==    by 0x569639D: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:57)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 4
==4228==    at 0x569639E: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:58)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c7f0 is 192 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid read of size 8
==4228==    at 0x56963AC: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:71)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c778 is 72 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Address 0x5d9c730 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 552 free'd
==4228==    at 0x4C32D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x56963DD: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:77)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228==  Block was alloc'd at
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x400AD4: main (n.c:45)
==4228== 
==4228== 
==4228== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==4228== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==4228== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==4228== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==4228== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==4228== 
^C==4228== 
==4228== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==4228==    at 0x5696467: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:53)
==4228==    by 0x400B9A: main (n.c:62)
==4228== 
==4228== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4228==     in use at exit: 3,745,320 bytes in 2 blocks
==4228==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 43,458,184 frees, 3,754,064 bytes allocated
==4228== 
==4228== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==4228==    by 0x5696F29: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==4228==    by 0x40093A: main (n.c:17)
==4228== 
==4228== 3,744,768 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==4228==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4228==    by 0x4009BA: main (n.c:26)
==4228== 
==4228== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4228==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4228==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4228==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4228==    still reachable: 3,745,320 bytes in 2 blocks
==4228==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4228== 
==4228== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4228== ERROR SUMMARY: 10000000 errors from 25 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

With 10000000 errors, I have no idea of what went wrong only that it went horribly so! I'd like to know where and why so many errors occured in the program.

Edit:

Added `s = 0;` before `goto write1` to make sure program enters the initial condition `if` statement. Thanks `@RetiredNinja`!

Eliminated `goto`. Thanks `@JohnBollinger`!

Eliminated the `k` loop and replaced `&CHUNK[j + k]` with `&CHUNK[j]`. Thanks `@Gerhardh`!

Comment: Take a look at your logic. As far as I can see `s == 0` is true only once so you hit the else case which closes the file and jumps back to the top. Since conditions have not changed it becomes an endless loop of closing the file and jumping back to the top.

Comment: ... and closing the same `FILE` twice produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Not related to Valgrind messages, but your logic searching for JPEG headers is broken. You are not supposed to search everywhere in the raw file. You shall only check the first 4 bytes of every 512 byte chunk. Also you are writing 512*512 bytes for each detected block instead of 512 bytes.

Comment: Also, although I am by no means an anti-`goto` campaigner, yours is not among the `goto` uses that I consider reasonable.  It breaks one of my cardinal rules for `goto`: never use `goto` to jump backwards (that's what looping constructs are for).

Comment: If you want to look at a different implementation that's clean and simple there's one in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565203/920069

Comment: A debugger would have caught this immediately:(

Comment: @JohnBollinger Wait, where do I close the same `FILE` twice?

Comment: @Gerhardh So, I should eliminate the `for` loop with `k` and use `fwrite(&CHUNK, 512, sizeof(BYTE), f)` instead?

Comment: Close but not correct. It is `&CHUNK[j]`

Comment: You will never enter that branch again `if(s == 0)` after you entered it once. For all other JPEG headers you will enter the `else` branch and close the file. And even not write that block at all. To be honest, I think you should start over again and watch the video from that CS50 task again. There is a rather detailed explanation how to do it.

Comment: @Gerhardh It works now. Thanks! So, using `malloc(size * sizeof(BYTE))` actually created an array of `CHUNK` with each element as larage as a `BYTE`?

Comment: @Gerhardh That code wasn't fully updated from yesterday. I had added a `s = 0;` right after closing the `f` so that the `if` condition would be entered to open the next `FILE`.

Comment: If you found that this was missing, then you should know what JohnBollinger was talking about. ;)

Comment: There is no array of `CHUNK`. `CHUNK` is a pointer that points to memory that is used as an array.

Comment: @Gerhardh I still have no idea of what he was saying. The program seems to give me images without that edit.