# I'm getting a Valgrind memory error on check50; I don't even know where to start troubleshooting

Tags: c, cs50

I have left some of the code out but it just involes opening the input file and then an If statement right after the comment "// Check if the bytes are JPEGs" ; but basically the program passes through all the necessary checks but fails the Valgrind check at the end. I have even rewatched the class and he uses free (variable that was malloc-ed) to free it; i tried swapping variables and everything but i still get an error.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int jpgs = 0; // Set an image counter for jpg names.
    unsigned char jpgbuffer[512]; // Buffer to look through 512 bits.
    FILE *images = NULL; // New file that is empty (used for jpg output).
    char *jpg = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)* sizeof(char)); // Allocate memory for the new file name for the images.

    // Use the fread given in the hints.
    while (fread(jpgbuffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(jpgbuffer), image) == sizeof(jpgbuffer))
    {
        // Check if the bytes are JPEGs.

        {
            // Copy everything after if the file IS a JPEG into a new file with name "00i".
            sprintf(jpg, "%03i.jpg", jpgs);

            // Open file in a write format.
            images = fopen(jpg, "w");

            // Incriment number of images.
            jpgs++;
        }

        //
        if (images != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(jpgbuffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(jpgbuffer), images);
        }

    }
    free(jpg);
    fclose(image);
    fclose(images);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: You aren't allocating enough space for `jpg`.

Comment: What is the exact error message from Valgrind?  For the exact code you show in the question?

Comment: You are doing `fopen` for every 512 block read--not what you want. And, you never do: `if (images != NULL) fclose(images);` to close the _old_ output stream

Comment: Do: `char jpg[100];` instead of the `malloc`

Comment: See my answer: [CS50 Recover (Pset4)- Images not Recovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565203/5382650) for some ideas.

Comment: @CraigEstey
 temp.c:54:10: error: attempt to call free on non-heap object 'jpg' [-Werror,-Wfree-nonheap-object] free(jpg);
 i get this when i try to compile it

Comment: Yes, because `jpg` is now a function scoped array--you can't do `free` on it. If you do, `char jpg[100];`, then _no_ `malloc` _nor_ `free(jpg);` There's no real need to use `malloc` for `jpg` here. But, if you want to, just do: `char *jpg = malloc(100);` [and _keep_ the `free(jpg);`]. The original issue was that `jpg` was not given enough space [as sj95126 mentioned]. That is: `malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)* sizeof(char))` is equivalent to: `malloc(1 * 1)` which is `malloc(1)` which doesn't have enough space.

Comment: _Side note:_ `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1--by definition regardless if `char` is 8 bits [as is mandated by POSIX] or not. `size_t` is always the _number_ of `char` you want. It is _not_ "number of _bits_". So, never do `X * sizeof(char)` as it's always just `X`

Comment: @CraigEstey here's my check50 after i changed to  "char *jpg = malloc(100);" 
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/9cc1a0547b9dd27c61856c1fdd4a3f0abc416aef

Comment: @CraigEstey i can also send the whole code if you'd like; in your code you didn't loop the 
( || buffer[3] = ) 16 times and i don't understand why you didn't but if i change it now it'll pretty much be cheating so as long as it is not the issue, i don't want to touch it

Comment: `sizeof(uint8_t)* sizeof(char)` is `1`. That's not enough memory.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, a few people suggested this and i've tried a few solutions such as using `char *jpg = malloc(100);` but [here's](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/9cc1a0547b9dd27c61856c1fdd4a3f0abc416aef) the error i get

Comment: Open the file and use `fseek()` to move to the end of the file, then use `ftell()` to return the number of bytes in the file.  Then allocate that number of bytes to ensure you can read the entire file with `fread()`. Or, you can scan forward in the file the find different jfif markers and read each part, see [JPEG File Interchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) for the marker and file layout. You can also use an initial value, see [cs50 pset4 Recover - why does writing entire file to memory fail check50?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608167/3422102)

Comment: @CraigEstey @DavidC.Rankin Thank you guys, after multiple hours of learning new code based on your guidances (you could probably tell by the structure of my code that i wasn't well-versed); I just decided to remove the malloc and use `char name[8];` and thank you Craig for linking your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565203/5382650) because the one [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608167/3422102) linked went way above my head.

Comment: Glad you got it working. There are always a number of different ways to *skin-the-cat* in C. As you master it (and it takes TIME, not a semester, not a year, but TIME), you will be able to choose from a number of different approaches. That way you can tailor your solution to whatever problem you are faced with. Keep up the good work.