# CS50 Trouble with valgrind on problem recover cannot reproduce valgrind message on local machine

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

I am having trouble getting my code to pass check50, when I run check50 valgrind comes back with this.

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:) recovers 000.jpg correctly
:) recovers middle images correctly
:) recovers 049.jpg correctly

:( program is free of memory errors
    valgrind tests failed; see log for more information.

checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
Invalid write of size 8: (file: recover.c, line: 84)
Invalid read of size 8: (file: recover.c, line: 84)
Invalid write of size 1: (file: recover.c, line: 88)
Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s): (file: recover.c, line: 88)
Invalid write of size 8: (file: recover.c, line: 88)
Syscall param write(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s): (file: recover.c, line: 102)
Invalid read of size 1: (file: recover.c, line: 102)
```

because of that error I try to run `valgrind` on my local machine to get the full log, I run `valgrind` like this

`valgrind -s --undef-value-errors=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -- ./recover card.raw`

and this

`valgrind ./recover card.raw`

but it says no leaks and no problems.

So I also tried running check50 locally and that failed worse than the online check with

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.

:( handles lack of forensic image
    expected exit code 1, not 127
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    expected exit code 0, not 127
:( recovers middle images correctly
    expected exit code 0, not 127
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    expected exit code 0, not 127

:| program is free of memory errors
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct byteRange
{
    size_t start;
    size_t end;
};
int findJPGS(FILE *file,  struct byteRange *,  size_t sizeofbyteRange);
int recoverJPGS(FILE *file, struct byteRange *jpgs, size_t numberJpgs);

int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("proper usage: ./recover IMAGE.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // open image file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1],  "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // read block and check for jpg.
    struct byteRange jpgs[50];
    int numberJpgs = findJPGS(file,  jpgs,  50);
    int result = recoverJPGS(file, jpgs,numberJpgs);

    fclose(file);
    return result;
}

int recoverJPGS(FILE *file, struct byteRange *jpgs, size_t numberJpgs)
{
    // go through byterange list and extract jpgs
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberJpgs; i++)
    {
        // create a reference to a single byteRange struct.
        struct byteRange range = {.end = 0,.start = 0};
        range = jpgs[i];
        // calculate the image size.
        size_t imageSize = range.end - range.start + 1;
        // create an array of imageSize.
        uint8_t image[imageSize];
        // seek to image start.
        if (fseek(file, (long int)range.start, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
            printf("fseek image number %lu is at fault\n",i);
            return 1;
        }
        // read image into image array.
        if (fread(&image, 1, imageSize, file) != imageSize) {
            printf("fread image number %lu is at fault\n",i);
            printf("returned value %lu != %lu\n",fread(&image, sizeof(uint8_t), imageSize, file),imageSize);
            return 1;
        }

        // write image to file.
        char fileName[50];
        sprintf(fileName,  "%03lu.jpg", i);

        FILE *output = fopen(fileName, "w");
        if (output == NULL)
        {
            printf("could not open file for reading\n");
            return 1;
        }

        fwrite(&image, 1, imageSize, output);
        // close file.
        fclose(output);
    }
    return 0;
}

// returns the number of jpgs found.
int findJPGS(FILE *file,  struct byteRange *jpgs,  size_t size)
{
    uint8_t block[512];
    size_t jpgStart = 0;
    size_t numberJpgs = -1;
    // read every 512 byte block in the file.
    while (fread(&block,  sizeof(uint8_t),  512,  file))
    {
        // check every byte of every block for a byte pattern.
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        {
            // if a byte contains this run the next level of check.
            if (block[i] == 0xff && i + 3 < 512)
            {
                // check the first and second bytes, and then check the first 4 bits of the third byte.
                if (block[i + 1] == 0xd8 )
                {
                    if (block[i + 2] == 0xff && (block[i + 3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
                        // if this is the first iteration don't bother setting an end byte
                        if (numberJpgs == -1)
                        {
                            numberJpgs = 0;
                            jpgs[numberJpgs].start = jpgStart;
                        }
                        // if this is not the first iteration bother setting the end byte, and set the beggining byte of the next set
                        else
                        {
                            jpgs[numberJpgs].end = jpgStart - 1;
                            numberJpgs++;
                            jpgs[numberJpgs].start = jpgStart;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            jpgStart++;
        }
    }
    jpgs[numberJpgs].end = jpgStart - 1;
    numberJpgs++;
    return numberJpgs;
}
```

Here is my Makefile

```
recover: recover.c
    clang -g -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -lm -o recover recover.c
```

So what is the problem with my code?

also bonus question why is my local check50 producing different results from the remote check50, and why are all of them different from raw valgrind?

Comment: Post a a [mre] not a snippet.  We can't tell from the snippet if it's the same file and line numbers that valgrind complains about.  Use the analyzer built into clang, you will have to lookup the syntax, but with gcc it's `-fanalyzer`.

Comment: To me, your questions lacks focus, as you are looking for help in resolving the "Invalid write" errors, or are you trying to figure out why the local and remote data is different?  Of the data you posted what is relevant to the problem at hand?  I think it's good you tell us what you tried, but we only care about what you tried to solve *this* problem.

Comment: hey thanks for the response I updated my questions and the attached code.

Comment: It is very unusual to read the input file _twice_. The cs50 recover problem is usually done in a single read pass. There are many cs50 recover Q&A on SO. Here is one of my answers: [CS50 Recover (Pset4)- Images not Recovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565203/5382650)

Comment: thanks for the input, I wanted to try and have low memory usage but now I see this was  a bad way of doing it.